# push notification ,api key and keystore dependency

Tags: android, push-notification

For implementing  push notification ,at server side api key needs to be created using SHA1 finger print(need application keystore and password) and pacakge name.
My  query is whether we get  the push notification from server if my application is signed using different keystore and password.
ie.is there any dependency like the keystore used for signing application must be used for generating api key

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of keystore therefore you will need 2 different SHA1 finger hashing:

**Debugging:**

You will create that hash using the debug keystore called `debug.keystore`.

**Production:**

When you are ready to publish you app, you have to sign it with your own keystore, that's the one you have to use to create the production SHA1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but my query is if at server side we are using api key obtained using production keystore whther we get the push to an application signed with  debug keystore

Comment: @NijuMt not it wont work. Use the appropriate API key based on  your app keystore signature.